# How to switch view to wysiwyg via execCommand in CKeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Context: I need to act via javascript after the insertion of a photo (I am trying to implement lazyload to CKeditor and it presents a few chalenges!).

This command switches to source view:

```
editor.execCommand( 'source' ); // works
```

This command does not switch to wysiwyg view:

```
editor.execCommand( 'wysiwyg' ); // does not work
```

What would be the proper command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
editor.setMode( 'wysiwyg' );
```

(I am using CKeditor 4.3).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: I understand, but it is so simple, I do not know what to add. It is either it works or it does not :)

Comment: I think the answer would be the most useful for the SO community if it explained *why* `setMode` works and why `execCommand` doesn't. Also, if you think the question is answered and you are not expecting any other solutions, accept the correct answer so that the question does remain open.  Thank you.

Comment: I understand completely, but I am not a specialist, so it is beyond my competencies to explain things! The system do not allow me to accept now, it imposes a delay of 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the mode in two forms:

1. Startup mode
2. After the instance is ready.

You can use this example

```js
CKEDITOR.config.startupMode = 'source' // Set source as start mode
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event) {
    try {
    // Make something with the editor in `source` mode
    event.editor.setMode('wysiwyg'); // Change the mode to wysiwyg
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```